# IndexedDB Query in Mobile Web

Tags: javascript

I use 'IndexedDB' in Mobile Web.
I want query like SQL syntax.
For example...

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE (X1 >= 1.1 AND Y1 <= 5.1) OR (X2 >= 1.2 AND Y2 <= 5.2)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

That's not the way IndexedDB works: IndexedDB doesn't use SQL syntax. Here's [MDN's documentation guide to IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB/Using_IndexedDB).

You might be thinking of [WebSQL](http://html5doctor.com/introducing-web-sql-databases/), which is a different thing. It's also not likely to achieve full browser support, so IndexedDB is probably more useful to you.

Comment: I know that. I mean, I don't use WebSQL or anything. I want use 'IndexedDB'. Because, I know that the performance of read beter than WebSQL. I tried 'index.openCursor(IDBKeyRange.bound(lowerBound,upperBound)), But the result was not wat i want. I want to get the same result as WebSQL Result.

Comment: OK, they way you've worded the question looks like you want to apply that SQL syntax literally to IndexedDB. As for your problem, maybe you need to set the closed/open parameters? (i.e. `IDBKeyRange.bound(0,1,true,false)`) But you should make a minimum working example, and post that in a new question.

Comment: @user3047781 that shouldn't be an answer to *this* question, that should be a *new* question. Also check out the [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JsStore for executing Sql query in indexeddb. It provides sql like api like - select, update, where, in , like etc.

So the code for above query in JsStore will be -

```
var Connection = new JsStore.Instance();
Connection.openDb('Database_name');
Connection.select({
    From: "TABLE",
    Where: {
        X1: {
            '>=': 1.1
        },
        Y1: {
            '<=': 5.1
        },
        Or: {
            X2: {
                '>=': 1.2
            },
            Y2: {
                '<=': 5.2
            }
        }
    },
    OnSuccess: function (results) {
        console.log(results);
    },
    OnError: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

You can execute almost all type of sql query using jsstore. For more take a look here - http://jsstore.net/